# Center canvas while keeping width and height

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I have a canvas I want to center on my screen AND keep the width and the height as if it was on the left corner of the screen. Any answer completely implemented in the  element only would be great!

To answer Bhuwan's question; Just make a canvas you like. I do not want you to use my specific canvas to solve this. Make it general!

OK to make this question easier to answer, here is what i use to test if answers work:

```
<canvas id="midcanvas"; style="width:300px;height:200px;border:red solid"></canvas>
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
function init(){document.getElementById("midcanvas").addEventListener("mousedown", getPosition, false);}
function getPosition(event){
var x = new Number();
var y = new Number();
if (event.x != undefined && event.y != undefined){x = event.x;y = event.y;}else{
x = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
y = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;}
x -= document.getElementById("midcanvas").offsetLeft;
y -= document.getElementById("midcanvas").offsetTop;

alert(x + " " + y)
}
</script>
```

Comment: where is your canvas...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` to center it and stretch the body to the full window height with `html, body { height: 100% }`.

This obviously only works if your `canvas` is the only element on your page.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<canvas style="width:200px;height:100px;border:thin black solid"></canvas>
```

Comment: the first part of the code is css and has to go in a `<style>` tag, but you could hardcode it into the element as well:
<html style="height:100%"><body style="height:100%;...">...</body></html>

Comment: `...<canvas id=midcanvas; ...` should be `...id="midcanvas"...`

Comment: OK `<html style="height:100%">
<body style="height:100%;display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center; flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;">
<canvas id="midcanvas"; style="width:200px;height:100px;border:thin black solid"></canvas>` worked. But it is sad that this could not be achieved only in the canvas itself nor is compatible with other elements. Good thing this is not necessary in my case. Thanks for your help! =]